# Is it a good idea to play a [mute] video in the splash screen

Tags: gui-design, video, splash-screen

I  am developing a health and fitness app. I am currently showing a video of a lot different people gymming in the splash screen and personally like it there. I was quite surprised that most apps don't use a video instead of a picture for their splash screens.

Could you help me understand why is it so? Is it just to reduce the size of the application? My video size is less than 10 MB and the rest of my application is not very huge either. In such a case is it okay to continue with keeping a video in the splash screen?

Comment: No offence, but this sounds like some cheesy gimmick that would have been popular in the 90s if it were economically affordable and technically feasible. I do usually like those repeating video backgrounds nowadays on some landing pages, but I can't imagine it makes good splash screen material.

Answer (score 2):

It's not trivial to do; which is why it's not popular.  It will become more common (then folk will start to get fed up with it and the pattern will plateau).

- The size of the video can be an issue - users may feel you are wasting their storage.
- It's expensive to make quality video so most teams don't have access to the resources
- The splash screen is usually used to cover startup time where the features the user wants are not yet available. If your video sting makes startup longer then you may be harming the experience not enhancing it.
- Apps that need first use flows can use video on a screen waiting for the user start the process - but then you are adding an overhead that only gets used once.

Comment: Agree with your points. Just for reference to some other reader of the answer: There are some really good videos available to be used for free on creative commons. So if point 2 of Aidan's answer is limiting you, consider exploring creative commons once.

Comment: *users may feel you are wasting their storage* Storage on the user's device is free, the problem is the bandwidth, especially if your Internet access is not unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays more and more sites are joining the trend of having a muted video being played in their landing pages. In fact, I'm also working in a fitness app and we've recently redesigned our landing to be on the cool side(?

Jokes aside. I know this case is different, but a big video of good quality just surprising you and welcoming you into the site can be stunning.

I don't know much about splash screens but there are many examples on the web of landing pages with videos, like airbnb and netflix some time ago.

That being said, a big problem that someone has pointed out at me lately is that if you don't choose the video images carefully, and it's colors are very similar to the colors of the text (if you happen to have text above the video images, like a 'welcome' text or a navabar at the top) they can easily blend together making reading a little bit difficult.

So maybe this could be a reason of why someone wouldn't want a video playing on a splash screen, especially if there is a lot of text to be displayed, but at this point I'm just speculating. All the other things @Aidan said seem reasonable too.

If you decide to keep it, just remember to pick the right pictures to make the experience effortless and friendly.